# Error "Unauthorized" when deleting record from smart device grid in Genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have an android app created with Genexus. In this, I have a grid created with work with smart device. I can insert and update records but when I try to delete it, after I confirm I get the error "Unauthorized", no other explanations. It works in local and in our test server, but not in our production server. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Surely something is missing in the deploy. Anyway, the best thing you can do is turn on the "log level = debug" property, under the "Logging" node of your main object, and see the error log to know specifically what is happening.